# Calculate linear percentage difference

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have two related datasets, with one of them that can be slightly below 0.

I am trying to calculate the 'linear' percent difference between the two.

I have written some example code:
perc[1] is the proper percentage method, however in the last two example cases, the percentage differences are not 'linear' for both sides (ie -87 compared to 700)- I need them to be equal or have some linearity in their calculation, whereas the last three methods are linear I guess. I like perc[3] as it is just the absolute difference and amplified, but kind of unitless. Maybe [4] or [5] is the most accurate for this use case, using the mean of the two as the denominator?

```
1, 8: [12.5, -87.5, 700.0, -700, -155.55555555555557, 155.55555555555557]
8, 1: [800.0, 700.0, -87.5, 700, 155.55555555555557, -155.55555555555557]
```

Statistics is not my strong point. Can anyone provide rational why I should use either [4] or [5]. I know that 0,1,2 and 3 are probably not the correct choices here

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def perc_calc(x,y):
    perc0=(x/y)*100 #Original one i used but is non-linear
    perc1=((x-y)/(y))*100   #Proper % method but still nonlinear
    perc2=((y-x)/x)*100    #Depends if use x or y
    perc3=(x-y)*100       #Just amplifying the real difference
    perc4=(x-y)/((x+y)/2)*100  #Difference by the mean 
    perc5=(y-x)/((x+y)/2)*100  #Opposite difference by the mean
    return [perc0,perc1,perc2,perc3,perc4,perc5]


x=np.random.uniform(-0.005, 1, size=600)
y=np.random.uniform(0.005,1,size=600)

plt.plot(perc_calc(x,y)[3])
plt.show()

plt.plot(perc_calc(x,y)[4])
plt.show()

def example(x,y):
    print(str(x)+', '+str(y)+': '+str(perc_calc(x,y)))
#Example Cases:
example(5,10)
example(-1,10)
example(1,8)
example(8,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference), the *relative percentage* is, in general, of the form

|x - y| / |f(x, y)|

The absolute value in |x - y| can be removed if you have a reference point, so as to get negative percentages. If that doesn't make sense to you, you should keep it.

The function |f(x,y)| is what is commonly called the **scaling factor**. You can choose between many options here, and it depends on the application.

You can take just f(x, y) = y, as you did in (1). This is usually done when **comparing experimental and theoretical values**, say, after measuring in some experiment; or when **measuring the change with respect to a past state**. But note that *it needs a reference point* (the theoretical value, or the value before the change was done) and it won't have the "linearity" property you are looking for, since your scaling factors change when swapping x and y (1/2 vs 1 if we use 1 and 2). This is because, for a value of 2, suddenly changing to 10 means a 400% increase, but a 10 becoming a 2 is a 80% decrease.

So you need some function f that doesn't change on swapping the parameters. This is known in mathematics as a **[symmetric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function)**. Many examples are shown in [the article referenced before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference). I suggest (|x| + |y|)/2, but try out the others to see what makes more sense.

```py
    perc6 = abs(x-y) / ((abs(x)+abs(y)) / 2) * 100
```

To test by plotting, try fixing a value for y, say 10, and do a scatterplot of x vs `perc_calc(x, 10)[6]`.